# Generating JSON with PHP with large number of rows

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm using the code below to generate a JSON, working correctly on the local WAMP server. But when I export the files to the WEB the script only generate the json with a few bank in the SELECT, if the query is greater than 10 results it does not generate anything, something that on the local server does not happen.

Has anyone had this problem? Would it be the case to edit the PHP.ini file or something?

```
   <?php
    //open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","vendas") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM os WHERE id_user = 15 and data_conclusao = '2017-03-02'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //create an array
    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($emparray);

    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your datas has UTF-8 caracters. If yes, try to replace your code by :

```
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $emparray[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` is a very muted function, if anything goes wrong while encoding, it simply returns false with no error message. If you are sure the `$emparray` really contains the needed data, your next debug step is to use [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php), which will help you to understand, what happens there.

One of the common reasons for such behaviour is non-encodable characters in the input string, or, often, occurences of binary secuences there. But you will be able to learn it only when you decode the error message - follow the reference I provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
You could encode each row, one row at a time instead of encoding it in one big operation.    
$db=mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die('Could not connect');
    mysql_select_db($db_name, $db) or die('');

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from listinfo") or die('Could not query');

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
        echo '{"testData":[';

        $first = true;
        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
            //  cast results to specific data types

            if($first) {
                $first = false;
            } else {
                echo ',';
            }
            echo json_encode($row);
        }
        echo ']}';
    } else {
        echo '[]';
    }

    mysql_close($db);
```

Comment: Seu código funcionou apenas no formato que eu precisei, eu tentei editá-lo mais do que o erro.

Comment: [
 {
"id_equipe":"100222",
"viatura":"123",
"nome1":"23456"
},
 {
"id_equipe":"1022220",
"viatura":"123",
"nome1":"23456"
 }
]